# GraphQL extract possible queries from a schema

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-schema

I have a graphql schema that i'm parsing

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
  age: Int
  posts: [Post!]!
}

type Post {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  body: String!
  author: User!
  comments: [Comment!]!
}

type Comment {
  id: ID!
  body: String!
  author: User!
  post: Post!
}

type Query {
  users: [User!]!
  user(id: ID!): User
  posts: [Post!]!
  post(id: ID!): Post
  comments: [Comment!]!
  comment(id: ID!): Comment
}
```

i want to get extract each possible query from it as a seperate string

in the above example,

String 1

```
type Query {
  users: [User!]!
}
```

String 2

```
type Query {
  user(id: ID!): User
}
```

String 3

```
type Query {
  posts: [Post!]!
}
```

String 4

```
type Query {
  post(id: ID!): Post
}
```

String 5

```
type Query {
  comments: [Comment!]!
}
```

String 6

```
type Query {
  comment(id: ID!): Comment
}
```

what is the best way to achieve this ? i'm using graphql javascript package